# Resource loading error for older netbean project

Tags: codenameone

I have a project that was last run earlier this year.  I've installed latest netbean with plugin but get the following when I start the app.

```
    java.io.UTFDataFormatException: malformed input around byte 200
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:656)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:564)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.loadTheme(Resources.java:1270)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.openFileImpl(Resources.java:303)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.openFile(Resources.java:269)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.<init>(Resources.java:189)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.open(Resources.java:768)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.open(Resources.java:688)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort$4.run(JavaSEPort.java:1720)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1056)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:873)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
```

I did create a sample app that worked and noticed that the properties tab shows it as a Gui Builder Project.  My older project does not show this.  I have tried comparing the properties but I do not see what is determining this.

I also copied the theme and the sample code into my project, used that as the main class.  The problem still persists.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you
Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We updated the format of the resource files so newer skin updates might collide with this project. If you use Update Client Libs it should work fine.

However, this change might also cause issues with newer skins if you are using versioned builds. Since the skin includes the native device theme within and we updated the theme file builtin the skin. You can understand our motivation for this change by looking at the before/after screenshots in our [3.8 release announcement](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/codename-one-3-8-live.html).

As a workaround for that problem you can switch a skin and download an older version of a device skin from our [skins project](https://github.com/codenameone/codenameone-skins/). You can then add that skin manually and use that.

Comment: Thank you, I did need to move to latest.